# Disabling an image map with CSS when using dynamically adjusting CSS

Tags: html, css, dynamic, imagemap

The desktop version of the site has an imagemap.  When the site goes into tablet or mobile view the imagemap needs to be disabled, so that the navigation area can display simpler version.   I have tried

`map {
    display: none;
}`

but the map persists.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you possibly expose more of your code? May in a jsfiddle or codepen? We can't tell the problem from just that small portion unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had an assignment with the same requirement. The way I got around it was by putting 2 `<img>` tags in my html file, one called "desktopImage" and the other "mobileImage" and linking the image map to the desktop image only. Then in my `default.css` doc I used `display:none` on the mobile `<img>` tag and vice versa in the `mobile.css` doc.

Eg:

In HTML file:

```
<img id="desktopImage" src="someimage.jpg" usemap="someimagemap" />
<img id="mobileImage" src="someimage.jpg" />
```

In default css doc:

```
#mobileImage
{
  display: none;
}
```

In mobile css doc:

```
#desktopImage
{
  display: none;
}
```

NOTE:

I know this thread is over a year old, but I was unable to find an answer to this question that didn't involve using `Javascript` or responsive image maps & browser plugins. This is most likely not the best way to do this, however for an intro `HTML` & `CSS` course assignment (my case) this'll do just fine

Comment: I had tried that ages ago and none of that worked for me.  I simply used responsive design.  No matter what I did, there were always pieces left in one browser or another.  Hide the image, and do something in responsive.  It's not a wonderful idea, but it really is the only solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a class of .map and this CSS inside your media query:

```
.map {
     display: none: !important
     position: absolute !important
     left: -9999px !important
}
```

Comment: No dice sadly. I have tried that as well as directly calling the map HTML element.

Comment: Try validating your HTML and CSS to see if you have errors, otherwise post the rest of your code.